# Проверка браузера

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть ли скрипт который проверяет браузер, если к примеру IE то перекидываем на страницу 
badbrowser.html на js?

То есть: пользователь зашел и скрипт будет проверять какой браузер, если к примеру IE то мы не даем ему доступ ко всему содержимому сайта, ну обычно перекидываем на какую нибудь страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос в IE, то пишите в заголовках так:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" > <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 no-formdata" > <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" > <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html class="no-js ie9" ><![endif]-->
```

А далее сравниваете с чем-то таким:

```
if ($('html').is('lt-ie9')) { location.href="/lt_ie9.html"; }
```

Если нужно конкретно версии других браузеров то подключите modernizr там уже всё готово в из коробки. Чем удобно навешивание классов на HTML что можно уйму багов которые есть в ie8,9 править через CSS, примерно так:

```
input { box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #000; }
.lt-ie9 input { border: 3px solid #000; }
```

Что касается мобильных версий есть такой самописный "костыль", меня спасал много раз, путем шаманства с регуляркой можно добиться многого, общий вид примерно такой:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { console.log('you are from mobile device'); }
```

Comment: Спасибо за отличный ответ :)